# com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerEJBException: Unable to initialize deferred EJB

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am migrating my application from EJB2.0 to EJB3.0 and at the same migrating server from WAS5.0 to WAS7.0, I did all the changes required to migrate the EJB and has no compile time errors however when I deploy my EAR into the server and hit the application it gives me an error -

```
NMSV0605W: A javax.naming.Reference object looked up from the context "ejblocal:" with the name "ejb/com/freight/xyz/UserLocalHome" was sent to the JNDI Naming Manager and an exception resulted. Reference data follows:

Reference Factory Class Name: com.ibm.ejs.container.util.EJBLocalInterfaceObjectFactory
Reference Factory Class Location URLs: <null>
Reference Class Name: com.freight.xyz.UserLocalHome
Type: EJBLocalInterfaceInfo

Content: com.ibm.ejs.container.util.EJBLocalInterfaceInfo@5bb95bb9
Exception data follows:
com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerEJBException: Unable to initialize deferred EJB.; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.freight.ecw.dto.User
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.initializeDeferredEJB(EJBContainerImpl.java:4938)
```

Along with this in the logs I can also see-

> Exception stack trace: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object.

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: It is not recommended <http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008724> to make non-critical application updates at the same time you're attempting a release-to-release migration.  That said, the NoClassDefFoundError sounds like a packaging or configuration issue.  Can you include the full stack trace and details about the EJB class hierarchy and how it relates to the User class?